# "Most Used" list in Windows 10 start menu disappeared forever, how to get it back again?

Tags: windows-10

Do you have any idea how to restore the **"Most Used"** applications list in Windows 10 start menu. It disappeared forever and I can't get it back again.

[image]

I tried every solution possible to get it restored again, but with no result at all.
I followed all possible solution mentioned here in superuser website and in so many websites too. I found all possible solutions in the link below for example. I even used a third party software for tweaking Windows 10 and I got nothing.

http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/6460-start-menu-most-used-apps-add-remove-windows-10-a.html

How can I fix this?

Comment: The one who gave me a -1 please let me know how to improve my question from you point of view!!. or at least say why I am getting -1!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what exactly causes this problem. But I know how to get it back using a third party tweaking software for Windows 10.

A free tool called [W10Privacy](http://www.winprivacy.de/english-home/) in explorer tab I have to uncheck the option `"Disable the collection of information about running programs and opened files"`. I also have to disable `"Do not show frequently used files"` too.

Then Restart and the List appears again.

I think the problem is some registry keys that affect the appearance of the that list indirectly. That's why solving the problem directly didn't solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem after selecting of "**Disable Microsoft Consumer Experience**" tweak in "Win10 Spy Disabler" tool. And reverting of this option did not have effect. Only the Windows System Restore helped me to restore the list again.